# create a user in installation

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, setup-project

I need to create a **local** windows user while installing my application.
The Setup should ask for username and password.
I'm using Setup Project.

How can I do that?

Comment: and you want to add a list of users in your setup project?

Comment: that's not necessary, but that would be nice.

Comment: A user of what? Your App, the Woindows domain?

Comment: If you don't add an user list how would you know if the user is correct?

Comment: @Gabriel: yeah, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Installer project  you should include a class that inherits from the Installer base class:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class MyInstaller: Installer
{
    public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        // add here the code that checks if the user is correct by opening
        // a Login form
        base.Install(stateSaver);
    }

    // Other override methods here if necessary
}
```

**Edit:**
Here is a link of how to create an windows user:[Create windows user example](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10012376/creating-a-windows-user-account.aspx)
So what you need to do is crate a form that accepts username and password as input and create the user from there.
Add this Form to your setup project and then call this form show method like this:

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            Form userCreateForm = new Form();
            userCreateForm.Show();
            base.Install(stateSaver);
        }
```

Hope this helps;

Comment: I didn't quite get it, can you provide me with more references plz?

Comment: @MBZ I would provide more references if I will understand the question better. From what I know the user limitation is not added from the install. The install should be performed anyway and the check for a user shuold be added in a Login form of the application.

Comment: It seems that I didn't ask my question clear enough.  I need my Setup to _Create_ a new _local_ user on the machine. a _user_ which will be used later for other purposes. So the installer need to ask for a new username and password from anyone installing the app (i.e. administrator). that's all

Comment: @MBZ I've edited my post with some extra information... hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use a dll and this call a webservice, this webservice get communication to database using a DAL (other dll with access a database).

in this link you can see the steps to create a custom installer class

http://devcity.net/Articles/339/1/article.aspx

create a form inside your dll and call it in the setup project.

HTH